# I'm getting a certain error on my TEMPMUTE command

Tags: python, discord.py

I have made a tempmute code or we can say I found one on stackoverflow. I copied the code but it doesn't seem to work. If anyone of you now and can help me thanks! The code is;

```
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=0, reason=None):
    if not member or time == 0:
        return
    elif reason == None:
        reason = 'No reason'
    try:
        if time_list[2] == "s":
            time_in_s = int(time_list[1])
        if time_list[2] == "min":
            time_in_s = int(time_list[1]) * 60
        if time_list[2] == "h":
            time_in_s = int(time_list[1]) * 60 * 60
        if time_list[2] == "d":
            time_in_s = int(time_list[1]) * 60 * 60 * 60
    except:
        time_in_s = 0
 
    tempmuteembed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 255, 0))
    tempmuteembed.set_author(icon_url=member.avatar_url, name=f'{member} has been tempmuted!')
    tempmuteembed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}  •  {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%Y at %I:%M %p')}")
    tempmuteembed.add_field(name=f'ID:', value=f'{member.id}', inline=False)
    tempmuteembed.add_field(name='Reason:', value=f"{reason}")
    tempmuteembed.add_field(name='Duration:', value=f"{time}")
    tempmuteembed.add_field(name=f'By:', value=f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=tempmuteembed)

 
    guild = ctx.guild
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == 'Muted':
            await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(embed=tempmuteembed)
            await asyncio.sleep(time_in_s)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            return
```

The error I'm getting is the following;

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "time".
```

Comment: What do you type in the chat for calling the command?

Comment: *tempmute @user 10m Test

Comment: `Member` objects will return `Name#Discriminator` when casted as string, so you can change `f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}'` to `f'{ctx.author}'` or `str(ctx.author)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Command`s have [`Converter`s](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) that are run on their arguments. Since `time` defaults to `0`, which is of type `int`, the library tries to convert `time` to an `int`. However, this conversion will fail if you give a unit suffix like `10m`, since `int('10m')` fails with a `ValueError`, which in turn raises `BadArgument`.

To fix this, simply add a proper type annotation to your `time` parameter:

```
from typing import Union
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: Union[int, str] = 0, reason=None):
```

Comment: now i get the error named
``module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strftime'``
on the part 
``tempmuteembed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}  •  {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%Y at %I:%M %p')}")``

@ZeroKnight

Comment: @wakandaᵗᶰᶜ Notice that the error mentions **module** 'datetime'. You're trying to call `strftime` on the `datetime` **module**, not the class. Either change your `datetime` import to `from datetime import datetime`, or use `datetime.datetime.strftime`. If you take the latter approach, you'll need to do the same for `now`.