# If Statement Is Not Being Reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a simple `discord.py` command that is, for some reason, not working. I'm trying to make a `slowmode` command, and there seems to be a fault in it. This is the code in the command:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def slowmode(self, ctx, seconds=5):
    if seconds == 'off':
      seconds = 0
    elif seconds == 'on':
      seconds = 5

    seconds = int(seconds)
    
    await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay=seconds)

    embed = discord.Embed(
      title='Slowmode Changed',
      description=f'The slowmode for {ctx.message.channel.mention} has been changed to: `{seconds}` seconds.',
      color=0x15E700
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The issue is, whenever I enter `$slowmode off` or `$slowmode on` (`$` is the prefix), I get the following error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "seconds".`

> I am clearly stating that, if `seconds` is either `on` or `off`, it will be turned to `5` or `0` respectively.

In addition, whenever I choose to enter an improper argument, as in a bunch of random letters, and I have a `try` and `except` block, the code immediately skips the `try` and `except` block and returns the exact error above. It is almost as if the code isn't there.

Comment: I don't see where you have printed out the value that is giving you the problem.  This is critical for diagnosis.

Comment: You are passing `seconds` as an int, checking if it's `on` or `off`, then casting that string to an `int`. I'd revisit that first. I don't see any prefixed `$` in your code either. Can you clarify?

Comment: I think discord.py itself is parsing the argument as an integer, due to the fact that its default value is an integer.  If you want it as a string that you can parse yourself, try giving the default as `seconds='on'`.

Comment: This is [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) at play; discord.py is indeed casting `seconds` as `int` automatically since your default argument is an `int`. You can either change it to `'on'` as @jasonharper suggested, or add a `Union` annotation from the `typing` module: `seconds: Union[int, str]`. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822744/1208424).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're noticing is due to the Commands extension's [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters). Specifically, the problem is with how you've declared your command's parameters:

```py
@commands.command()
async def slowmode(self, ctx, seconds=5):
```

`seconds` has an `int` default argument, so the Converter is casting it to an `int`. Since you also accept string values for this argument, it's going to raise `BadArgument` when it attempts to convert `'on'` to an `int`. There is a [special converter for `typing.Union`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-union) that you can use to annotate your `seconds` variable to correctly accept `str` and `int` inputs:

```py
from typing import Union

@commands.command()
async def slowmode(self, ctx, seconds: Union[int, str] = 5):
```

In addition, you should check the type of `seconds` before attempting to check for string values:

```py
@commands.command()
async def slowmode(self, ctx, seconds: Union[int, str] = 5):
    if isinstance(seconds, str):
        if seconds == 'on':
            seconds = 5
        elif seconds == 'off':
            seconds = 0

# no longer needed
# seconds = int(seconds)
```

This way, you also no longer need to explicitly cast `seconds` to `int`.

Comment: Neither casting to int nor `isinstance` are necessary. If `seconds` is not a string then the comparisons will fail anyway, so no need to check if it's a string... As to converting to int, either the argument is already an int, or if it's "on" or "off" it will be re-assigned as an int anyway...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Have you read what the [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) do, and why `BadArgument` is raised? If someone invokes the `slowmode` *command* with a string argument, and the coroutine parameter is left as `seconds=5`, `BadArgument` will be raised before anything in the `slowmode` coroutine is run.

Comment: That's not related to what i was talking about... I was talking about the code after your fix with the `Union`... Assuming `BadArgument` is not raised, then `seconds` can still be either an int or a string and my comment above still holds...

Comment: Try doing `5 == "on"` and see what happens

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at. If someone invokes `slowmode on` in Discord, then `seconds = 'on'`, and needs to be converted to a predefined `int` value, which is handled by the conditional. But if it's invoked as `slowmode 30`, then `seconds = 30` and `30 == 'on'` will raise, hence guarding that conditional with `isinstance`.

Comment: My point is exactly that it doesn't raise any error. It simply returns `False`... This is why I urged you to try out in a console `5 == "on"` to see what happens

Comment: Yikes, I don't know why I had it in my head that that comparison raised a `TypeError`. My mistake entirely. Though I'd still argue that *one* comparison via `isinstance` is better than *two* comparisons that would always fail when `seconds` is an `int`.

Comment: You might had in mind the fact that relational comparisons will indeed raise an error, like `5 > "on"`. But equality will always simply return `False` for type mismatch

Comment: Regarding your second argument, you forget the flip-side of that coin: if `seconds` is a string, you will have two conditionals evaluated to `True` instead of one... To be honest this is really insignificant ;)